# Editing a just inserted record

Tags: php, javascript, crud

I am making a crud application ui in javascript and i was wondering how this can be done.Basically,i want to be able to edit a record that i have just inserted.For instance in grids such as jqgrid and extjs,this is possible and i am having a hard time figuring out how that is accomplished.In plain php and html,i would have an hidden input that holds some hidden value like

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
```

I have this fiddle that i am using to investigate what normally happens http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/EgHP7/

Edit:

This is how i am inserting new records

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
  url: "update_data.php",
   data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){

  $("ol#update").prepend(html);
  $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
   document.getElementById('content').value='';
  $("#flash").hide();

  }
 });
```

This is the php file

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isSet($_POST['content']))
{
$content=$_POST['content'];
mysql_query("insert into messages(msg) values ('$content')");
$sql_in= mysql_query("SELECT msg,msg_id FROM messages order by msg_id desc");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($sql_in);
$msg=$r['msg'];
$msg_id=$r['msg_id'];
}
?>

<li class="bar<?php echo $msg_id; ?>">
<div align="left">
<span class="hello" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" style=" padding:10px"><?php echo $msg; ?> </span>
<span class="delete_button">
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>"  class="update_btn">Edit</a>
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="delete_update">Delete</a>
</span>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please don't mix clientside and serverside processing. Rephrase your answer if you know what exactly you want.

Comment: It was an example!.The php was there by mistake.

Comment: He could be talking about doing it using AJAX. Obviously you have to have a back-end that implements the actual CRUD operations, but some people don't differentiate much in that respect.

Comment: OK, but what is your question?

Comment: @flapjack That's not the point. Your question as it stands can't be answered as it's by no means clear what you're after. You're showing no indication of how you're doing this insert, and your description of what you want is sketchy at best.

Comment: @Thor84no: Yes, he *could*. If it was so, he'd need to *ask* "I have this backend. What do I need to change for ...?"

Comment: @Bergi,i know your kind.You just want to be sarcastic.

Comment: @flapjack: No, I'm not. Sorry, but I can't find a question in your request, so please clarify.

Comment: @Thor84no I am doing the insert via ajax using jquery and the example i fiddled is in js.

Comment: You need to show your PHP that inserts the record. Most likely you'll use a `last_insert_id` function of some sort.

Comment: So, let me see if I understand. Is your problem that after inserting (I assume that means sending it off to some PHP backend), you need to get the ID of object that was created so that you can make any modifications from then on be an update rather than insert next time you click save?

Comment: @Thor84no Its better of if i got the jqgrid and look into it,but thanks for your length explanation,plus all others.

Comment: I'd look to check whether the `$content` variable contains an ID and make it an update if it does. Coincidentally, don't get the ID of the latest insert that way, there's no guarantee some other thread didn't insert something between your insert and your next select. You can get the actual ID that was generated directly using `mysql_insert_id()`.

Comment: Okay,i was kind of avoiding the last_inserted_id path.Will mysql_insert_id() still work if two people are editing the table at the same time?.I got that idea from http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?249861-mysql_insert_id-What-is-the-chance-of-error&s=ffc297a0d7bc3656682bc0a7128b04eb&p=1800310&viewfull=1#post1800310

Comment: `mysql_insert_id` gets the most recently inserted id from the current connection. Other database connections do not change it. Using `mysql_insert_id` or an equivalent in whatever library you are using is the safest way to get the last inserted ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using values such as `Date.now()` as a temporary id then insert that value into the database and into the client-side maybe using LocalStorage and then when you want to edit that you just have to compare that value to the one in the database.